# How to inject cookies in a webview swift?

Tags: swift, cookies

I have cookies stored that i retrieved from a server. Using such cookies, i want to open a webview which logs in the last session as stored by said cookie. How can I inject those cookies

Answer (score 1):

I think the quickest way would be to instantiate HTTPCookie and add it to web views configuration.
Something like this:

```
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [...])!

/* Something like this
let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: [.domain: "something.org", 
                                     .path: "/",  
                                     .name: "cookieName",
                                     .value: "cookieValue",
                                     .expires: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 31556926)])!
*/

webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)
```

Comment: it writes error, expected declaration after webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie)

Comment: Can you give me a little more info, pls? Were you able to create some kind of cookie?

Comment: i was able to create a cookie from a kickstarter page with its subsequent properties. I want to use such cookie to log on to a webview from the last session i.e. without having to log into kickstarter

Answer (score 0):

```
let wkCookieStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default().httpCookieStore
if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
   for cookie in cookies {
          wkCookieStore.setCookie(cookie) {
                    }          
  }
}
```

I use this method to sync cookies from httpcookiestorage to wkcookiestorage, hopefully as of now you may have understood the wkwebview cookie storage is different and nsurlsession cookie storage is different.

i sync the cookies on

> webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation
>   navigation: WKNavigation!)

This way you won't miss any cookies need to be set to the subsequent requests made by the webpage.